# How do I replace a JSON list to print to a CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm using an API to gather some data that comes to me in JSON format. I'm using json.loads to import the data and can successfully write it to a CSV. Unfortunately, the data comes in in a format that I don't want so I'd like to reformat the json list.

I've tried creating a new list and assigning the JSON list to the desired list. I get the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests
import json
import csv

response = requests.get(url).text //json source
data = json.loads(response)
newsdata = (data["response"]["docs"])


// These two lines reformat the date to what I want it to look like
newsdate = [y["pub_date"] for y in newsdata]
newsdate = [y.split('T')[0] for y in newsdate]

newsdata["pub_date"] = newsdate // This line is what I've tried to replace the json

newssnip = [y["snippet"] for y in newsdata]
newshead = [y["headline"]["main"] for y in newsdata]

for z in newsdata:
    csvwriter.writerow([z["pub_date"], //This is the JSON data i want to reformat
                        z["headline"]["main"],
                        z["snippet"],
                        z["web_url"]])
```

I expected the newsdata["pub_date"] to be overwritten when I assigned newsdate to it but I get the following error instead: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Thank you for your help! :)
EDIT:
I've uploaded an example json response here on github called "exmaple.json": https://github.com/theChef613/nytnewsscrapper

Comment: you should at least give some sample `z` data

Comment: good point! I've uploaded it here on github as "example.json": https://github.com/theChef613/nytnewsscrapper

Answer (score 0):

That error is saying that newsdata is list and is therefore not subscriptable with a string. If you post the raw JSON data returned or also `print(type(newsdata))` to figure out what class newsdata is and how to work with it. It's also possible that newsdata is a 2D (or N-d) array where the first element is the key and the second element is the value.